# Rent program adding rent

Tags: java

I have a if statement that checks if the 
`customer id = arraylistID and c.isRenting = false;`

after adding customer id if the above conditions are met.

I run it again and it still allows it condition to be met even though `IsRenting = true`

```
boolean isRenting = false;

for (Customer c : customers) {
    if (rentCustID == c.getCustID() && c.isRenting() == false) {
        isRenting = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (isRenting == true) {
    System.out.println("Customer not renting! can rent a bike\n");
    customers.get(rentCustID).setRenting(true);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Customer renting! can't rent a bike\n");
    menu();
}
```

Comment: return CustID; and
 for isRenting()     return isRenting;

Comment: Shouldnt' `if (isRenting == true) {` be `==false` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (Customer c : customers) {

        if (customers.get(rentCustID).isRenting() == false) {

            customers.get(rentCustID).setRenting(true);

            break;
        }

        else {

            System.out.println("Customer renting! can't rent a bike\n");
            menu();

        }

    }
```

Didn't know how to fix the problem so I just changed the order and this worked